# Problem when using DATEADD and DATEDIFF to get the start day (Monday) of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I use this sql to get the start day of the week (Monday) when users enter date of other days

@StartDate has format (yyyymmdd)

SQL:      `CAST(convert(varchar(12),DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,0,@StartDate),0),112) as int`

The problem is that when entered date is from Tuesday to Saturday, it returns to the correct Monday of the current week. Yet when the entered date is sunday, it returns date of monday next week.

can anybody tell me what i did wrong

 thank you

Comment: why are you storing your datetime as an integer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get first day of week in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)

Comment: @MartinSmith we have had alot of questions about getting the first day of the week, the one you linked to doesn't work for finding the first day though. You can test my claim here: set datefirst 7;SELECT [start_of_week] = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '1900-01-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-3), '1900-01-01');

Comment: @MartinSmith if you notice the small change in my solution compared to your linked solution you may notice the correct result

Comment: Why are you using `'1900-01-01'`? The answer uses `'1905-01-01'`

Comment: @MartinSmith because i am looking for the last monday and not the last sunday

Comment: Oh yes, missed that. Looks like the accepted answer doesn't work as a general solution then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sunday belongs to same week as monday, this will make monday the first day of the week. It should fix your query

```
set datefirst 1
```

This syntax doesn't care what day the database is considering first day of the week, it will calculate the monday of the real week of your @StartDate.

```
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @StartDate)/7, 0)
```

You can test with this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
SELECT DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate)))
```

Also, don't forget to set the correct dateformat first:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
```

Answer (score 1):

You know how I do this?

```
SELECT max(cal_date)
FROM calendar
WHERE cal_date <= CURRENT_DATE
  AND day_of_week = 'Mon'
```

No arithmetic. Fast, runs in .000082 seconds on my old box. The calendar table is indexed; it can be used efficiently in joins on huge tables.

And most important--you can tell the query is obviously right.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk but more databases *should* have a calendar table.