# SQL Server 2005: arithmetic with dates

Tags: sql-server

I would like to write a simple `SELECT` statement in SQL Server 2005 which does the following computation with date arithmetic:

Starting from the present date (this means `getdate()`), determine the previous Monday, and then subtract 70 days from that Monday, showing in output the resulting date.

How could I achieve this?

My difficulty is mainly to determine *the previous Monday*.

Of course, if `getdate()` is Monday, the previous Monday is `getdate()`

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

UltraCommit

EDIT: Please note that in Italy the first day of the week is Monday and not Sunday, so if the input is Sunday, July 29th, 2012, the output has to be 23rd July, and not 30th July.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will retrieve  monday for the current week

```
Select DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

and then you need to subtract 70 from the above day

```
SELECT Dateadd(DAY,-70,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
```

Edit : Please go through the answer posted in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)

Monday is displayed as Current Week because [DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) which indicates the 1st day of the week is set to monday .In order to set it to Sunday ,you need to change the setting to Sunday

```
 Set DATEFIRST 7
```

Else as suggested in the above SO link ,you need to change your code

```
 DECLARE @dt DATE = '1905-01-01';
 SELECT [start_of_week] = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, @dt, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), @dt);
```

Comment: EDIT: Please note that in ITALY the first day of the week is MONDAY and not SUNDAY, so if the input is Sunday, July 29th, 2012, the output has to be 23rd July, and not 30th July.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to write: SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,(GETDATE())-1), 0)   ??  I have subtracted 1 to GETDATE, so it works in Italy, using SUNDAY as first day of the week, I have realized only a shift.

Comment: Yeah that will surely gonna work but i have edited the code so that you should be aware of the problem .In case if the 1st day of the week changes to some other day ,you should not end up adding or subtracting values from the above function

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind contribution!

Answer (score 2):

To get last monday look at 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/20/sql-server-find-monday-of-the-current-week/

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.  It will find the past Monday for the current week.

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) MondayOfCurrentWeek
```

To substract 70 days, just add -70 to the end:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)-70 as SomeMondayInHistory
```

Comment: EDIT: Please note that in ITALY the first day of the week is MONDAY and not SUNDAY, so if the input is Sunday, July 29th, 2012, the output has to be 23rd July, and not 30th July.