# Get timestamp for start of the week and end of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In order to get timestamp for start of the week and end of the week I do the following.

```
    SET @currentTimestamp = DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE());
    SET @currentDate = DATEADD(s, @currentTimestamp, '19700101');
    SET @currentWeek = DATEPART(wk, @currentDate);
    SET @starter = 1451654325; 
    SET @weekSize = 604800; 
    SET @beginOfWeek = @starter + ((@weekSize) * (@currentWeek - 2));
    SET @endOfWeek = @starter + ((@weekSize) * (@currentWeek - 1));
```

It is necessary for the future for query like...

```
    Submit_Date BETWEEN @beginOfWeek AND @endOfWeek
```

For doing something as part of current week.

Can I make the code more elegant and beautiful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422248/previous-monday-previous-sundays-date-based-on-todays-date

Comment: This is probably better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sub-query results directly in `BETWEEEN` condition:

```
SELECT LastSunday, DATEADD(dd, -7, LastSunday) AS SundayBeforeThat
FROM (SELECT CAST(GETUTCDATE() - DATEPART(dw, GETUTCDATE()) + 1 AS DATE) AS LastSunday) A
```

- Here we use `CAST(... AS DATE)` to truncate time portion;
- Deduct `DATEPART(dw, GETUTCDATE()) + 1` to get last Sunday;
- `DATEADD(dd, -7, LastSunday)` with negative number to go back one week.

Actually, I would probably `INNER JOIN` this subquery `ON Submit_Date < LastSunday AND Submit_Date >= SundayBeforeThat` to filter the target query:

```
...
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT CAST(GETUTCDATE() - DATEPART(dw, GETUTCDATE()) + 1 AS DATE) AS LastSunday
    ) w
 ON Submit_Date >= DATEADD(dd, -7, w.LastSunday)
AND Submit_Date < w.LastSunday
```