# Get Previous Friday in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datepart

How to get previous friday in SQL Server?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
select (7 -datePart(dw, getdate()+3)) +1
```

Comment: Isn't every Friday the last Friday of a week?

Comment: do you mean last friday of a month
?

Comment: Give us a couple example dates and what you want the output to be.

Comment: at any given point of time.. I wanted to get last firday

Comment: what does select @@DATEFIRST return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Previous Monday & Previous Sundays date based on todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422248/previous-monday-previous-sundays-date-based-on-todays-date)

Comment: Please see my answer below.  This should work for any date you input into the @date parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Use mod like this:

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()
declare @dow int = datepart(dw,@date)
declare @mod int = @dow % 7 +1
select cast(dateadd(d,-@mod ,@date) as date)
```

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 0):

If your week starts on Sunday, then here's a one-liner:

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK
              ,DATEDIFF(WEEK, '1900-01-05', DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) - 1, GETDATE()))
              ,'1900-01-05') AS [Last Friday]
```

The query counts the number of weeks since 1900-01-05 (which is a Friday) to today's date minus 1 week.  This number of weeks is added to 1900-01-05 to get the previous week's Friday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 select convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(DD, -1 - DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE())))
),CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE())))),101)
It will give you previous friday of every week