# SSRS report @To parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I need last Sunday date with whole day time count. By using this

```
 DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -0,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Weekday(today),Today)
```

I am getting time As `12AM`, but I need all day time.

Comment: please format your code and give more contextual information...

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code` i am using two parameters as @from and @to date's , i need to get last monday date as default value in from date and  i need to get last sunday date as default value in to date i need to get records between this two date's,from date starting from 12AM i am getting that day records ,for to(sunday) starting  12 AM i am unable to get sunday records. i want default value as last sunday and get that day records too. @Tommy Brettschneider

Comment: If you are using SQL Server as a back end, then have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422248/previous-monday-previous-sundays-date-based-on-todays-date

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code` i am getting date of last sunday but that day records are not coming,if i check time of that date is is showing 12AM @Harry

Comment: @saikumar can you show what your data looks like?