# Grouping by Week in SQL, but displaying full datetime?

Tags: sql, t-sql

the following statement:

```
group by datepart(wk, createdon)
```

Groups the selected rows according to the week in which they fall.  My select statement shows the following:

```
SELECT 
    datepart(wk, createdon) week,
```

How do I display the actual datetime of the week("12-10-2012"), instead of the number ("12")?

Comment: Do you want to display the actual value of createdon for each row? If you do, then you can't "group" the rows according to the week. Do you want to display some specific date for any given week, like the date of the corresponding Monday, or some such? If so, we need to know which one.

Comment: What do you want to display if you have multiple dates in the same week?

Comment: I'd like to display the actual date of the beginning of the week - like "date of" + createdon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get first day of week in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're wanting to group by week but also return the full datetime. You must include the selected fields in aggregate columns.
Thusly should work:

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk, createdon) week, createdon
FROM TableName
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, createdon), createdon
```

Works on MSSQL2008R2

Edit:
As the OP seems to want the starting date of the week, SO has the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server).

Comment: This is a well-written answer, but it doesn't appear to address the original poster's needs, as this approach doesn't group rows together that are in the same week. (Unless I've missed something?)

Comment: LOL, as I said, *if* I understand...which it seems now the OP wants to display the "date" of the starting "day" of the week.

Comment: Therefore, I think SO already has the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server).

Comment: Good catch! Looks plausible to me. You might update your answer saying so.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using a cte with `ROW_NUMBER` instead:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(wk, createdon) ORDER BY createdon)
     , DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,createdon), 0) As Week
     , *
   FROM dbo.Table
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Everyone:  don't overlook this answer.  It offers up an elegant way of doing what we formerly did with temporary tables in the past.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can't group by a week, and then show constituent parts of it, i.e. days. You will need group by the date instead.