# SQL Server - Finding the first day of the week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've been looking around for a chunk of code to find the first day of the current week, and everywhere I look I see this:

```
DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Every place says this is the code I'm looking for.

The problem with this piece of code is that if you run it for Sunday it chooses the following Monday.

---

If I run:

```
SELECT GetDate() , DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Results for today (Tuesday):

```
2013-05-14 09:36:39.650................2013-05-13 00:00:00.000
```

This is correct, it chooses Monday the 13th.

---

If I run:

```
SELECT GetDate()-1 , DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK,0,GETDATE()-1),0)
```

Results for yesterday (Monday):

```
2013-05-13 09:38:57.950................2013-05-13 00:00:00.000
```

This is correct, it chooses Monday the 13th.

---

If I run:

```
SELECT GetDate()-2 , DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK,0,GETDATE()-2),0)
```

Results for the 12th (Sunday):

```
2013-05-12 09:40:14.817................2013-05-13 00:00:00.000
```

This is NOT correct, it chooses Monday the 13th when it should choose the previous Monday, the 6th.

Can anyone illuminate me as to what's going in here? I find it hard to believe that no one has pointed out that this doesn't work, so I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: I believe the root of the issue is the use of the date 0 which in SQL Server resolves to '1900-01-01' - this was a Monday.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get first day of week in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Pondlife: Not really. The issue is why different Mondays are returned depending if the date is a Sunday or any other day of week.

Answer (score 6):

It is `DATEDIFF` that returns the "incorrect" difference of weeks, which in the end results in the wrong Monday. And that is because `DATEDIFF(WEEK, ...)` doesn't respect the `DATEFIRST` setting, which I'm assuming you have set to 1 (Monday), and instead always considers the week crossing to be from Saturday to Sunday, or, in other words, it **unconditionally** considers **Sunday** to be the **first day of the week** in this context.

As for an explanation for *that*, so far I haven't been able to find an official one, but I believe this must have something to do with the `DATEDIFF` function being one of those SQL Server treats as [always deterministic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx). Apparently, if `DATEDIFF(WEEK, ...)` relied on the `DATEFIRST`, it could no longer be considered *always* deterministic, which I can only guess wasn't how the developers of SQL Server wanted it.

To find the first day of the week's date, I would (and most often do actually) use the first suggestion in [@Jasmina Shevchenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16548760/297408):

```
DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date), @Date)
```

`DATEPART` does respect the `DATEFIRST` setting and (most likely as a result) it is absent from the list of *always deterministic* functions.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = GETDATE()

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date), @Date) AS DATE)

SELECT CAST(@Date - 2 AS DATE), CAST(DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, @Date-2), 0) AS DATE)
```

Results:

```
---------- ----------
2013-05-12 2013-05-13
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a `SET DATEFIRST` function which allows you to tell it what the first day of the week should be.  SET DATEFIRST = 1 tells it to consider Monday as the first day of the week.  You should check what the server's default setting is via @@DATEFIRST.  Or you could simply change it at the start of your query.

Some references:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)

Comment: DATEDIFF(WEEK) disregards the DATEFIRST setting, and that is why the wrong Monday is returned for a Sunday date (when @@DATEFIRST = 1).

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me like a charm:

Setting moday as first day of the week without changing DATEFIRST variable:

```
-- FirstDayWeek    
select dateadd(dd,(datepart(dw, case datepart(dw, [yourDate]) when 1 then dateadd(dd,-1,[yourDate]) else [yourDate] end) * -1) + 2, case datepart(dw, [yourDate]) when 1 then dateadd(dd,-1,[yourDate]) else [yourDate] end) as FirstDayWeek;

-- LastDayWeek
select dateadd(dd, (case datepart(dw, [yourDate]) when 1 then datepart(dw, dateadd(dd,-1,[yourDate])) else datepart(dw, [yourDate]) end * -1) + 8, case datepart(dw, [yourDate]) when 1 then dateadd(dd,-1,[yourDate]) else [yourDate] end) as LastDayWeek;
```

Setting sunday as fist day of the week without changing DATEFIRST variable

```
select convert(varchar(50), dateadd(dd, (datepart(dw, [yourDate]) * -1) + 2, [yourDate]), 103) as FirstDayWeek, convert(varchar(50), dateadd(dd, (datepart(dw, [yourDate]) * -1) + 8, [yourDate]), 103) as LastDayWeek;
```

You can change [yourDate] by GETDATE() for testing