# Get Current week days from monday to sunday

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried solution for this is like.

```
select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)as StartDate ,
   (select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) + 5) as EndDate
```

it gives monday-saturday in result, but on Sunday it gives me next week days

I want sunday as last day of week and Monday as First Day of week..

Please Help...

Comment: You need to take a look to this answer [Get first day of week in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7169656/1297603)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, use `SET DATEFIRST 1` to specify that monday is the first day of the week. However, that doesn't solve the issue here. Use this syntax instead:

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0) AS StartWeek,
       DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 5) AS EndWeek
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22401/0)</kbd>

[SET DATEFIRST (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

```
1    Monday
2    Tuesday
3    Wednesday
4    Thursday
5    Friday
6    Saturday
7    (default, U.S. English) Sunday
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i got the required solution from this.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks

Comment: it show only days from Monday to today not all days of week

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 yes, but that was OP's requirement if you look at his question. Maybe he used the wrong title

Comment: No , please the question again , he said " I want sunday as last day of week and Monday as First Day of week.."

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 well you can read his comment, his approach and he accepted it. So i guess i understood it correctly. But if you want all days of the current week im sure there is another question on stackoverflow which answers it. If not feel free to ask it. Best way is to create a calendar table if you dont have it already.

Answer (score 1):

You just add 6 days instead of 5.

```
select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) as StartDate 
select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) + 6) as EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    @d datetime,
    @f datetime;

SET @d = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,getdate())-48,0) --start of week from a year ago
SET @f = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,getdate()),0) --start of current partial week;

create table #weeks (
    week_starting datetime primary key
)

while @d < @f
begin
    insert into #weeks (week_starting) values (@d)
    set @d = dateadd(week,1,@d)
end
select * from #weeks

drop table #weeks
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be excessively complicated, but it was tons of fun.

--This first part is to get the most recently occurred monday.

--It starts by creating a table which will hold all dates until the most recent monday, then sets the min of that table to the @mondaythisweek variable.

```
declare @dateholder table (
    thedate date,
    theday varchar(10)
    )

declare @now datetime
set @now = GETDATE()

;with mycte as (
    select
        cast(@now as date) as "thedate",
        DATENAME(dw,@now) as "theday"
    union all
    select 
        cast(DATEADD(d,-1,"thedate") as date) as "thedate",
        DATENAME(DW,DATEADD(d,-1,"thedate")) as "theday"
    from
        mycte
    where
        "theday" <> 'Monday'
    )
insert into @dateholder
select * from mycte 
option (maxrecursion 10)

declare @mondaythisweek date
set @mondaythisweek  = (
select min(thedate)
from @dateholder
)
```

--This part creates a table from @mondaythisweek to the next sunday

```
;with mon_to_sun as (
    select
        @mondaythisweek as "dates",
        DATENAME(dw,@mondaythisweek) as "theday"
    union all 
    select
        cast(DATEADD(d,1,"dates") as date) as "dates",
        DATENAME(dw,cast(DATEADD(d,1,"dates") as date)) as "theday"
    from mon_to_sun
    where "theday" <> 'Sunday'
)
select * 
from mon_to_sun 
option(maxrecursion 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())/7, 0) AS 'StartWeek(Monday)',
       DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())/7, 6) AS 'EndWeek(Sunday)'
```

> With Time

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())/7, 0) AS 'StartWeek(Monday)',
       DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())/7, 6)), '23:59:59') AS 'EndWeek(Sunday)'
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE forweek

(
@year varchar(max)
--,@SearchParam varchar(max)

)

AS
BEGIN
Declare @StartDate date,
@d date,
@f date,
@l date,
@currentyear varchar(max);

```
 Set @year=@year
 Set @currentyear =(SELECT YEAR(getdate()) as year)
```

if ( @year =  @currentyear)
begin
SET @d = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,getdate())-datediff(wk,@year+'-01-01',getdate()+1),0) --start of week from a year ago
SET @f = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,getdate()-1),0) --start of current partial week;
SET @l = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,getdate())-datediff(wk,@year+'-01-01',getdate()+1),6)
create table #weeks (dateid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
week_starting date ,
week_End date
)

while @d <= @f
begin
insert into #weeks (week_starting,week_End) values (@d,@l)
set @d = dateadd(week,1,@d)
set @l = dateadd(week,1,@l)
end
--select * from #weeks
Select (convert(varchar, w.week_starting, 101)+'-'+ convert(varchar, w.week_End, 101)) as weekrange, w.week_starting as weekstarting ,w.week_End as weekEnd from #weeks w
order by w.dateid desc
--where (convert(varchar, w.week_starting, 101)+'-'+ convert(varchar, w.week_End, 101)) like '%' + @SearchParam + '%'

drop table #weeks
end

else
begin
SET @d = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,@year+'-12-31')-datediff(wk,@year+'-01-01',@year+'-12-31')+1,0) --start of week from a year ago
SET @f = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,@year+'-12-31'),6) --start of current partial week;
SET @l = dateadd(week,datediff(week,0,@year+'-12-31')-datediff(wk,@year+'-01-01',@year+'-12-31')+1,6)
create table #weeks1 (dateid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
week_starting date ,
week_End date
)

while @d <= @f
begin
insert into #weeks1 (week_starting,week_End) values (@d,@l)
set @d = dateadd(week,1,@d)
set @l = dateadd(week,1,@l)
end
--select * from #weeks1
Select (convert(varchar, w.week_starting, 101)+'-'+ convert(varchar, w.week_End, 101)) as weekrange, w.week_starting as weekstarting ,w.week_End as weekEnd from #weeks1 w
--where (convert(varchar, w.week_starting, 101)+'-'+ convert(varchar, w.week_End, 101)) like '%' + @SearchParam + '%'
order by w.dateid desc
drop table #weeks1

end

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).