# Start of the week (Monday) - Query gives an incorrect date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query to get the start of the week (Monday) for the current date. It breaks when the date is first of the month and a Sunday. Not sure how to solve this issue. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,'2017-01-01'),0)
```

Comment: I use this in my queries: `SET DATEFIRST 1
select DATEADD(dd, (1-DATEPART(dw, '2017-01-01')), '2017-01-01')` (SET DATEFIRST 1 is required to fix the American date style left behind by default by the DBA)

Comment: I tried SET DATEFIRST 1, the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are finding the no. of weeks from date 0 to the supplied date. 0 is actually '1900-01-01' which was a Monday. Therefore,DATEDIFF finds the number of completed weeks from this date until the supplied data. Thats why DATEDIFF for March 27 2016 returns 6065 (as it is the end of a week) and March 26 2016 returns 6064 (as it is still not the end of a week). 
This is already explained in this link - [Get first day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server/7169656)

Comment: Thanks. That link was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code mentioned below. Is that what you are looking for?. Let me know if this works

```
declare @date date = '2017-01-01'
select case when dateadd(dd,-datepart(dw,@date)+2,@date) < dateadd(dd,-day(@date)+1,@date)
                        then @date else dateadd(dd,-datepart(dw,@date)+2,@date) end as firstdayoftheweek
```

Comment: It is giving me 2017/01/02. The start of the week for that date should be 2017/12/26.