# SQL: Returning Monday of the week not working for Sundays

Tags: sql, date

I want to input a date and have it return the Monday of that week, but at my company the week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday. I tried using `SET DATEFIRST 1` to make Monday the first day of the week, but this didn't help me with Sundays.

code:

```
DECLARE @proddate datetime = '6/12/2016'
SET DATEFIRST 1; SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@proddate), 0) MondayOfWeek
```

returns:

```
6/9/2016 -> 6/6/2016
6/12/2016 -> 6/13/2016 (should be 6/6/2016)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @proddate), @proddate)
```

Comment: This works and I've implemented it in my code. By the way, do you happen to know what was wrong with my original code?

Comment: Your code was good for normal usage, this way is more sensitive to the DATEFIRST statement. TBH I would normally use your original code myself..

Comment: There's a great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server) that explains why this works.