# Given a Week Number, Return the First Day of the Week in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

This will give me a week number based on a date:

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk, '7/27/2016') AS [Week]
```

For example, that returns 31.

Now, what I need to do is find the first day of that week, and return it in a short date format.  For example:

```
Given Week: 31
Return First Day of Week: July 24
```

Or

```
Given Week: 52
Return First Day of Week: Dec 25
```

I believe the default first day of the week is Sunday, and that's the date I need.

I've seen several posts here that come close, but none get me all the way there.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the "first" day of the week? Some use Sunday, some use Monday.

Comment: Good question.  I meant to specify that.  I think the default is Sunday, and that's what I'd like.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: @jpw, I saw that one.  But that question, like all that I've seen, assume you start with a date.  I need to start with a number (31) and return a date.

Comment: So what you really need is the date of the Sunday which is in a given week of the year ("first" is too malleable to be used in this context), right?

Comment: USE THIS LINK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server

Comment: @JonWay I saw that one. But that question, like all that I've seen, assume you start with a date. I need to start with a number (31) and return a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I helps to read this from the inside out. I added numbered comments to help.

```
declare @weekNum int;set @weeknum = 52;
select 
-- 3.  Add number of weeks
dateadd(wk, @weekNum, 
    --2.  first day of week 0 for that year (may belong to previous year)
    dateadd(ww, datediff(wk, 0, 
        --1.  First date of the year (week 0)
        dateadd(YEAR, datediff(year,0, getDate()),0)
     ),-1) -- -1 here because 1900-01-01 (date 0) was a Monday, and adding weeks to a Monday results in a Monday.
)
```

We can combine steps two and three, since they both add weeks:

```
declare @weekNum int;set @weeknum = 52;
select 
    --2.  first day of week 0 for that year (may belong to previous year) + number of weeks
    dateadd(ww, @weekNum + datediff(wk, 0, 
        --1.  First date of the year (week 0)
        dateadd(YEAR, datediff(year,0, getDate()),0)
     ),-1) -- -1 here because 1900-01-01 (day 0) was a Monday. Adding weeks to a Monday results in a Monday
```

Also, I think your example for week 31 is off by a week. You can see the full set for the year like this:

```
with weeks as 
(
    select top 52 row_number() over (order by  object_id) as wk  from sys.objects
)
select wk,
    --2.  first day of week 0 for that year (may belong to previous year) + number of weeks
    dateadd(ww, wk + datediff(wk, 0, 
        --1.  First date of the year (week 0)
        dateadd(YEAR, datediff(year,0, getDate()),0)
     ),-1) -- -1 here because 1900-01-01 (day 0) was a Monday. Adding weeks to a Monday results in a Monday
from weeks
```

Comment: Ok yeah, something is weird here.  SELECT DATEPART(wk, '7/27/2016') returns 31.  But, if I put 31 back into your query, I get 7/31/2016.  Given a date, the first day of the week that date is in can not be after that date.

Comment: The problem is the first day of the year is not a sunday. How do you want to account for that? Do you want to show a day from last year? Should the result for week 1 be 2016-01-03 or 2015-12-27? And if you make a change for this, it will shift _everything_ forward, including week 52 (do you want to allow for a week 53?).

Comment: I see your point.  What we have now is week 1 starting on Jan 3, which ignores Jan 1 and Jan 2.  I need to include those dates.  So, we better have week 1 starting at Dec 27, 2015.

Comment: Easy enough to add a -1 with the week num, but remember that this will now change the results for week 52 from your question, with a partial week 53 at the end of the year. I'd also want to test this in a year that does start on sunday. You may also need a case statement to not make the adjustment if Jan 1 is sunday.

Comment: Got it.  We now have 53 weeks in a year.

Comment: Technically, in leap years you can have 54 weeks if the year starts on a Saturday (assuming Sunday is you first day of the week.)  It's a corner case, but it bit me a few years back.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my calculations. The idea is to take Jan 1st of the year and make arithmetic from there.

```
declare @year int=2016, @wk int=31
--A) Single chain calculations
select case datepart(weekday,cast(concat(@year,'-01-01') as date))
            when 1 then dateadd(wk,@wk-1,cast(concat(@year,'-01-01') as date))
            else dateadd(wk,@wk-1,
                  dateadd(day, 1/*8 if you want "first full week"*/ - datepart(weekday, cast(concat(@year,'-01-01') as date)),
                          cast(concat(@year,'-01-01') as date))) end

--B) the same in a better readable form    
;with tmp as (
select  cast(concat(@year,'-01-01') as date) jan01
)
select case datepart(weekday,jan01)
            when 1 then dateadd(wk, @wk-1, jan01)
            else dateadd(wk, @wk-1, dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(weekday, jan01), jan01)) end frstDay
from tmp
```

Comment: 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: `concat` was introduced in SQL Server 2012. For earlier versions you can use `cast(@year as varchar)+'-01-01'`. Also CTE first appear in 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using DATEDIFF and DATEADD (line #3 is one line of code to get the value you are looking for).  This may be similar to the accepted answer.

I am posting since this is a break down that I have used in a function when I documented for myself.

```
--1. Get the number of Weeks since Monday, January 1, 1900
select DATEDIFF(wk, 0, '01/01/2016') -- 6052 Weeks

--2: Take the value since 1900 + Number of Weeks - 8 Days get you to Sunday.
select DATEADD(wk, 6052 + (31), -8);

--3. Put it all together..
select DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, '1/1/2016' ) + (31), -8); --=2016-07-24
```