# How to get Data from Monday to today's Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Have a sample data like this

```
DECLARE @T Table (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(10),DOB DATE)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (1,'Mohan','2016-11-13')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (6,'Manasa','2016-11-10')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (2,'Raj','2016-11-07')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (3,'Manny','2016-10-30')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (4,'kamal','2016-11-01')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (5,'Raj','2016-11-08')
```

Query :

```
SELECT * from @T WHERE 
DOB >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -1) 
AND DOB <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 5)
```

Here I'm unable to get from Monday to Today's Date means 2016-11-10.I'm Covering all the dates which are coming in this week .

I want to get data like this

```
ID  Name    DOB
6   Manasa  2016-11-10
5   Raj     2016-11-08
```

suggest me the best way

Comment: There is another date within this range which is `'2016-11-07'`, do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: yes it's sample data so we can give the output if it is in scope

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/7168874/1048425

Comment: please check next weeks date it should not come

Comment: @mohan111 So you mean whenever we run the query, you want to get all the current week's (for that particular week) DOB's right?

Comment: Please mark the answer if it is correct for you.Thanks.

Comment: @balaji i have tried it in other way.any way thanks for suggesting the answer

Answer (score 1):

DATENAME() will solve your problem.

```
DECLARE @T Table (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(10),DOB DATE)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (1,'Mohan','2016-11-13')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (6,'Manasa','2016-11-10')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (2,'Raj','2016-11-07')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (3,'Manny','2016-10-30')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (4,'kamal','2016-11-01')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (5,'Raj','2016-11-08')

SELECT * from @T 
WHERE DATENAME(WEEK,DOB) = DATENAME(WEEK,GETDATE())
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0),@EndDate DATE = GETDATE() SELECT * FROM @T WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,DOB,@StartDate) <= 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,DOB,@EndDate) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T Table (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(10),DOB DATE)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (1,'Mohan','2016-11-13')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (6,'Manasa','2016-11-10')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (2,'Raj','2016-11-07')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (3,'Manny','2016-10-30')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (4,'kamal','2016-11-01')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (5,'Raj','2016-11-08')


SELECT * from @T WHERE 
DOB >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
AND DOB <= DATEADD(wk, 0,GETDATE());
```

This is giving me proper result.