# equivalent for trunc and to_date(to_char in conjunction

Tags: sql, datetime, datediff, datepart

I hate so much when it come down to convertion dates from one database system to another. I understand the concept of trunk and to_date used in oracle but

From:
`nFirstDayOfWeek := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(nDate, 'MONTH'), 'D'));`

To SQL Server I tried:

`SET @nFirstDayOfWeek = DATEPART(datediff(@nDate, 'MONTH'), 'd');`

No Luck.

Error msg: `Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ISHOLIDAY, Line 18
The datediff function requires 3 argument(s).`

Thank you.

Comment: well you need three [**arguments**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) `DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well is a Function called: IsHoliday and setting declaration, they trying to retire Oracle database and switch over SQL Server 2012, so that line is a declaration as SMALLINT; 
is a function that Visual basic call to compare for tax payments. to make sure doesn't get process during the weekend.

Comment: is  there another way around to convert this with another method: `nFirstDayOfWeek := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(nDate, 'MONTH'), 'D'));` to sql server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first day of week in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server)