# Is there a way to use SET DATEFIRST in a view using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I can't save my view when I use this query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 6

SELECT       
    ISNULL ((SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Qte_achat * Prix_unit, 0) + 
                        ISNULL(qte_achat2 * prix_unit2, 0)) AS SUM_Achat
             FROM dbo.Achat
             WHERE (DATEPART(week, date_achat) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())) 
               AND (YEAR(date_achat) = YEAR(GETDATE())) 
               AND (used_by_vent = 'false')), 0) AS SUM_Achat
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first day of week in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server) In other words: use those answers to calculate the start and end of the week (agnostic of `DATEFIRST`) and filter based on those dates. Bonus is a sarge-able query

Comment: thank you but not this

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using query that depends on such settings. It could easily break your query.

Since your week is start on 'Saturday', use a base reference date that is `Saturday` like `1900-01-06` in calculation to determine the week

```
(DATEDIFF(day, '1900-01-06', date_achat) / 7 = (DATEDIFF(day, '1900-01-06', getdate()) / 7
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `Datefirst` is a property of the session.

You can't set it in a view. Suppose you had a query that selected from two different views and you *could* set `datefirst` differently for each, which setting would the query honour?

You need to set it before using your view, or in a stored procedure.