# Show only full weeks - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dayofweek, week-number

how could I display only full weeks from my dataset? So if my week starts on Monday 1st of August to the 14th, that would be considered a full week. Whereas the one starting on the 8th is considered half and I'd like not to show it.

Many thanks in advance!

Table name:RRA
date column: seriesdate

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: Why is the week of 2022-08-08 considered a half-week? It's a full week to me...

Comment: ...or do you mean to exclude dates that start in the _current_ ("now") week?

Answer (score 0):

- My answer assumes that you want to select rows where the `seriesdate` value is in a week that is *not* the current week.
- Assuming that your `seriesdate` column is indexed then a SARGable (i.e. *fast*) way to implement this filter is to just exclude rows with dates *after* the start-of-the-current-week. Like so...
- Also...

  - Note that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (the ISO SQL equivalent of SQL Server's `GETDATE()`) uses the database server's local timezone which might not be the timezone used by your data.

    - If so, replace `DECLARE @now datetime2(7) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` with a date/time-literal like `DECLARE @now datetime2(7) = '2022-08-10 12:34:56';`
    - Note that most SQL Server setups will default to `DATEFIRST 7` (Sunday).

```sql
SET DATEFIRST 1; -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql

DECLARE @now datetime2(7) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; -- or '2022-08-10 12:34:56'

-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server
DECLARE @startOfThisWeek date = DATEADD( day, 1 - DATEPART( weekeday, @now ), @now );

SELECT
    q.*
FROM
    [RRA] AS q
WHERE
    q.[seriesdate] < @startOfThisWeek
```